# Find if string contains the substring without Java.substring

Tags: java, string, algorithm

> Design a function hasCheated(String s1, String s2, int N) that returns true if the two strings, `s1, s2` have a common substring of at least length N. **Without using .contains, .substring**

Was the desired approach to convert to char arrays or something like that?

I am considering finding the longest common substring and then seeing it again `N`. What are some approaches for this?

Comment: You are apparently looking for a [String searching algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm).

Comment: *"What are some approaches for finding the longest common substring?"* Why don't you try searching the web? There are already answers out there. See [`longest common substring`](https://www.google.com/search?q=longest+common+substring).

Answer (score 2):

Finding the longest common substring first will be slower than just checking whether there is a match of at least a given size. You can stop as soon as you get a match, even if there could have been a longer one.

I would build a hash set (or a hash map if the requirement is more complex) which represent all the sub strings of length N for one (without actually creating those substrings) and use it to scan strings of length N for likely matches.

You could do this in O(M) time where M is the length of longest String.

You can create a substring class like this.

```
class Substring {
    final String s;
    final int offset, length, hashCode;

    Substring(String s, int offset, int length) {
        this.s = s;
        this.offset = offset;
        this.length = length;
        this.hashCode = hashCode(s, offset, length); // define to taste
    }

    public int hashCode() { return hashCode; }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
       if (!(o instanceof Substring)) return false;
       Substring ss = (Substring) s;
       if (hashCode != ss.hashCode || length != ss.length) return false;
       for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
           if (s.charAt(i) != ss.s.charAt(i))
               return false;
       return true;
    }
}
```

To build the HashSet, you can do the following in `O(n)` where n is s1.length()

```
Set<Substring> substrings = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < s1.length() - n; i++) {
    Substring ss = new Substring(s1, i, n);
    substrings.add(ss);
}
```

To do the search for matches, you can do the following in `O(n)` where n is s2.length()

```
for (int i = 0; i < s2.length() - n; i++) {
    Substring ss = new Substring(s2, i, n);
    if (substrings.contains(ss))
         return true; // found a match.
}
```

Comment: Perhaps, to be a *useful* answer, you should explain further how you would build a hashmap of substrings without creating substrings.

Comment: @Andreas added a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

So, without `contains`, `substring` I am assuming you mean not to use any Java APIs. Here is an implementation using dynamic programming:

```
public static boolean hashCheated(String a, String b, int N) {
    int m = a.length();
    int n = b.length();

    int max = 0;

    int[][] dp = new int[m][n];

    for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
            if(a.charAt(i) == b.charAt(j)){
                if(i==0 || j==0){
                    dp[i][j]=1;
                }else{
                    dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j-1]+1;
                }

                if(max < dp[i][j])
                    max = dp[i][j];
            }

        }
    }

    return (max >= N);
}
```

Comment: This is O(m*n) for time and memory usage.

Comment: yes, this is one of the many approaches possible without using Java APIs and every approach has time-space tradeoff. May be not the best approach.

Comment: If you consider time to get a working solution (i.e. time of developer), it's pretty good. :)

Comment: What do you mean by *"not to use any Java APIs"*? Your code uses both `length()` and `charAt()`, which are both Java API methods. They are no less "Java APIs" than `contains()` and `substring()`.